# como actualizar DGV en el formulario padre, desde un formulario hijo al cerrarlo

Tags: c#

espero me puedan aclarar dudas.
tengo el DGV en el formulario padre en el cual solo muestra el contenido de una tabla en la base de datos al momento de abrir el formulario padre el DGV lista los datos, en el formulario padre desde un boton abre un otro formulario que seria el hijo en este puedo agregar, editar informacion que viene desde el DGV padre. les explico selecion un campo del DGV que esta en el formulario padre al hacer click en el boton que lees mencione abre otro formulario en el cual muestra lo que seleccione en unos textbox.

todo lo mencionado anteriormente lo hace bien. lo que necesito saber es al momento de cerrar el formulario hijo, y regresarme al formulario padre vuelva a listar o vuelva  cargar con el dato que se agrego o con la informacion edita que se realizo en el formulario hijo.

formulario padre

cuando inicia o abre el formulario se carga en el load y mando a llenar el DGV

```
 private void frmDetalleIngreso_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listar_tingreso();
        }

 public void listar_tingreso()
            {
                dgvListartingreso.DataSource = xDetalleIngresoModel.cdo_listarti();
                dgvListartingreso.Refresh();

                if (dgvListartingreso.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                 //CENTRAR TITULO DE LAS COLUMNAS
                 dgvListartingreso.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
             
                //CAMBIAR EL ESTILO DEL GRILLA DEL DGV
                //SunkenVertical:SOLO MUESTRA LINEA VERTICAL
                dgvListartingreso.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SunkenVertical;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["NUMERO"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["NUMERO"].Width = 70;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["ORDEN PROVEEDOR"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["ORDEN PROVEEDOR"].Width = 100;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["ESTADO"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["ESTADO"].Width = 60;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["PROVEEDOR"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["PROVEEDOR"].Width = 150;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["ARTICULOS"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["ARTICULOS"].Width = 70;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["CREADO EL"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["CREADO EL"].Width = 100;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["CANCELADA/RECIBIDA EL"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["CANCELADA/RECIBIDA EL"].Width = 120;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["idproveedor"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["idproveedor"].Width = 50;

                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["TOTAL"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    dgvListartingreso.Columns["TOTAL"].Width = 70;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Existe Compras Pendientes o Realizadas");
                }
            }
```

tambien en el formulario padre aqui
aqui con un boton abro el formulario hijo y mando las variable, tabmien las cargo en el load
porque necesito tenerla directement en los textbos ya cargados

```
private void btnaddOrden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductoModel xProductoModel = new ProductoModel();

            DataTable dt;
            dt = xProductoModel.cdo_listarProductosLC(txtaddOrden.Text);

            //SI TRAE INFORMACION EL DATATABLE DE LA BD ENTONCES QUE LO MUESTRE
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var row = dt.Rows[0];
                //lblNumOrdenSist.Text;
                string codbarra2, nombprod2, nombprov2, nombcat2, nombmarca2;
                int idorden2,idcat2, idmarca2, idprov2;
                decimal pc2;

                codbarra2 = row["CODIGO"].ToString();
                nombprod2 = row["DESCRIPCION"].ToString();

                nombcat2 = row["CATEGORIA"].ToString();
                idcat2 = Convert.ToInt32(row["idCategoria"].ToString());

                nombmarca2 = row["MARCA"].ToString();
                idmarca2 = Convert.ToInt32(row["idMarca"].ToString());

                nombprov2 = row["PROVEEDOR"].ToString();
                idprov2 = Convert.ToInt32(row["idprov"].ToString());
                
                pc2 = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"].ToString());

                idorden2 = Convert.ToInt32(lblNumOrdenSist.Text);

                frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador frmdiDGVb = new frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador(
                idorden2,codbarra2, nombprod2, nombprov2, nombcat2, nombmarca2, idcat2, idmarca2, idprov2, pc2,idprov3);
                frmdiDGVb.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
           

 MessageBox.Show("No Existe Producto que mostrar", "Información");
        }
    }
```

FORMULARIO HIJO
CREO las misma variables que recibo del formulario Padre y las cargo en el load para que la muestre directamenteen los textbox

```
 public partial class frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador : Form
    {
        DetalleIngresoModel xDetalleIngresoModel = new DetalleIngresoModel();
        ProductoModel xProductoModel = new ProductoModel();

        string codbarra2, nombprod2, nombprov2, nombcat2, nombmarca2, idprov3;
        int idingreso2, idcat2, idmarca2, idprov2 ;
        decimal pc2;

        Boolean Editar = false;

        public frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador(int idingreso2,string codbarra2, string nombprod2, string nombprov2, string nombcat2, string nombmarca2,
            int idcat2,int idmarca2, int idprov2,  decimal pc2,string idprov3)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.idingreso2 = idingreso2;
            this.codbarra2=codbarra2;
            this.nombprod2=nombprod2;
            this.nombprov2=nombprov2;
            this.nombcat2=nombcat2;
            this.nombmarca2=nombmarca2;
            this.idcat2=idcat2;
            this.idmarca2 = idmarca2;
            this.idprov2 = idprov2;
            this.pc2 = pc2;
            this.idprov3 = idprov3;
        }

        private void frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblidingreso2.Text = idingreso2.ToString();
            lblcodigobarra.Text = codbarra2;
            lblnombprod.Text = nombprod2;
            lblnombprov.Text = nombprov2;
            lblnombcat.Text = nombcat2;
            lblnombmarca.Text = nombmarca2;
            lblidcat.Text = idcat2.ToString();
            lblidmarca.Text = idmarca2.ToString();
            lblidprov.Text = idprov2.ToString();
            lblpc.Text = pc2.ToString("N2");

            lblprov3.Text = idprov3.ToString();
        }
}}
```

asta aqui todo bien con lo que hago. estuve leyendo este articulo practicamente es lo mismo a lo que necesito pero se que hace en la interfaz ai me pierdo no e logrado implementarlo bien.

talves con su ayuda pueda hacerlo.

que hago para actualizar el dgv en el formulario padre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo que necesitas es que los 2 formularios se comuniquen. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, y acá es donde entra en juego tu análisis con respecto al tema de acoplamiento, reutilización y esas cosas. Tambien tenes que tener cuidado con el tema de los Close() y Dispose() de los formularios.

Yo te paso una solucion asi muy generica para que puedas adaptarla a tu desarrollo. Esta consiste en utilizar una interfaz para comunicar los formularios.

Creo la interfaz:

```
public interface IForm
{
    void actualizarDatos();   
}
```

El codigo del formulario padre quedaria algo asi:

```
public partial class frm_principal : Form, IForm
{
     private void cargarGrilla()
    {
        //toda la logica que carga la grilla o X componente
    }
    
    public void actualizarDatos()
    {
        //este es el metodo que me obliga a implementar la interfaz
        //aca podes poner toda la logica que quieras
        //como ejemplo, solamente hago que este metodo llame al cargarGrilla()
        cargarGrilla();
    }
    
    //este metodo sirve para abrir el formulario hijo, es una forma de cargar un formulario hijo sin estar creando muchas instancias del mismo
    private void BotonQueLlamaAlHijo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is frm_hijo);
        if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed == true)//valido que el formulario no este creado o que haya sido liberado utilizando dispose()
        {
            //si no existe lo crea y lo llama
            frm = new frm_hijo(this);//este this es para pasar como parametro el puntero del Form Padre
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            //si existe solo lo llama y se carga el form
            frm.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

El codigo del hijo quedaria algo asi:

```
public partial class frm_hijo : Form
{

    Form caller;
    //Si no queres utilizar interfaces aca tener que declarar un form del tipo padre
    //frm_principal caller; ← de esta forma

    public frm_editar_socio(Form padre)//si no usas interfaces tenes que recibir un frm_principal
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.caller = padre;

    }
    
    //este es el metodo que cierra el form y actualiza al padre
    private void btn_salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea salir de esta ventana?","Alerta!!!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (resultado == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            var aux = caller as IForm; // si no usas interfaz esto no es necesario
            //pero si es necesario que validez que el formulario padre no sea null
            if (aux != null)
            {
                aux.actualizarDatos();

            }
            this.Dispose();
        }             
    }

}
```

Comment: Saludos Franco, revisando y probando.

Comment: fiera @franco, funciono  a la perfeccion, mas adelante dejare como deje le codigo para aquellos que anden buscando algo igual y lo tenga parecido

Comment: todo esta igual solo agregue parte del codigo,en el formulario ijo 'public partial class frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador : Form
    {'Form caller;'  en esta parte siempre estan las variablesolo agrege el final 'public frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador(, Form padre){InitializeComponent();this.caller = padre;}' dentro de un boton coloque esto el codigo de cerrar, en el form padre 'public partial class frmDetalleIngreso : Form, IForm' ,despues esto para actualizear el dgv ' public void actualizarDatos(){listar_tingreso();}'

Comment: Form frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador);if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed == true){frm = new frmDetalleIngresoDgvBorrador(misvariablealfinal,this);frm.ShowDialog();}else{frm.BringToFront();} crean la interfan y la dejan igual como lo hace @Franco,

Comment: Genial que te funcione, tene en cuenta que por ahí no se justifica usar una interfaz si solo es para actualizar, por ahí con solo pasar el puntero alcanza. Yo usaría una interfaz en el caso que fuera un formulario principal o que tengan varios métodos en común. Si te interesa podes buscar mas formas de comunicar formularios, y te vas a encontrar con que hay formas mas sencillas que esta o mucho mas complejas pero recontra reutilizables.